# Why can't Haskell infer Tree type?

Tags: haskell

I followed the book to define Tree data type, but show doesn't work correctly. Why?

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)

test = show EmptyTree
```

gives the error message:

```
No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of ???show???
The type variable ???a0??? is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Show a => Show (Tree a)
    -- Defined at /Users/gzhao/Documents/workspace/hsTest2/src/Tree.hs:3:62
  instance Show Double -- Defined in ???GHC.Float???
  instance Show Float -- Defined in ???GHC.Float???
  ...plus 25 others
In the expression: show EmptyTree
In an equation for ???test???: test = show EmptyTree
```

Comment: How are you running this code? Are you using interpreter (ghci)? This line: `test = show EmptyTree` is not valid Haskell syntax, so you are probably not pasting all of your code.

Comment: @rburny I think the OP has that in the source file.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that `EmptyTree` has type `Tree a` for *any* type `a`. Even though it won't actually affect the final output, the compiler wants to know which `a` you mean.

The simplest fix is to pick a specific type, e.g. with `show (EmptyTree :: Tree ())`. This uses the *unit* type `()`, which is in some sense the simplest possible type, but you can also use any other type that has a `Show` instance, like `Int`, `String` etc.